# Complete integral of PDE $x^2p^2+y^2q^2-4=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following non-linear first order PDE before me :

$x^2p^2+y^2q^2-4=0$

I have to find  two complete integrals for this PDE.

I wrote the Charpit equations as below:

$\dfrac{dp}{2p^2x}=\dfrac{dq}{2yq^2}=\dfrac{dz}{-2(p^2x^2+q^2y^2)}=\dfrac{dx}{-2px^2}=\dfrac{dy}{-2qy^2}$

$1$st and $4$th equations give:

$pdx+xdp=0$
or

$px=a$ for some constant $a$

This gives $p=\dfrac{a}{x}$

Putting this value of $p$ in given PDE, we get:

$q^2=\dfrac{4-a^2}{y^2}$

These values of $p$ and $q$ give us one complete integral on solving $pdx+qdy=dz$

When it comes to the second integral, I try to consider $2$nd and $5$th equations which, unfortunately, gives us first integral only as answer.

I also noticed that
$xdp+ydq+dz=0$ using first three equations.
But this proved to be of no use to me either.

How can I find another complete integral in this case? Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)^2+y^2\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right)^2-4=0$$

HINT :

The change of variables :
$$\begin{cases}
X=\ln(x^2)\\
Y=\ln(y^2)
\end{cases}$$
transforms the original equation into the classical eikonal equation :
$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial X} \right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial Y} \right)^2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

You could just substitute the value of p and q you've found (which are independent of each other) in the equation -> **{dz = p dx + q dy}** and integrate this new equation.

The required solution is something like **z = a log x + root(4 - a^2) log y**